# Contour integral with power of sine

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I am trying to show that, for $\alpha > 1$,

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \sin(x^{\alpha}) dx = \sin \left ( \frac{\pi}{2\alpha} \right ) \int_{0}^{\infty} \exp(-x^{\alpha}) dx$$

The approach I've used has been to take the imaginary part of the integral of $\exp(i x^{\alpha})$ over the line. Then I'm trying to compute this with a wedge contour with angle $\pi/2\alpha$. The horizontal segment and the diagonal segment are fine, but I'm having trouble showing that the arc integral goes to zero, i.e.

$$\lim_{R \to \infty} \int_{0}^{\pi/2\alpha} \exp(i R^\alpha \exp(i \alpha \theta)) R i \exp(i \theta) d\theta = 0$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the integral as the imaginary part of

$$\int_0^{\infty} dx \, e^{i x^{\alpha}}$$

Then follow [this derivation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/422574/how-do-you-integrate-int-0-infty-expitk-mathrm-dt-for-k-in-bbb-n/422587#422587) to get that

$$\int_0^{\infty} dx \, e^{i x^{\alpha}} = e^{i \pi/(2 \alpha)} \int_0^{\infty} dx \, e^{-x^{\alpha}}$$

Taking imaginary parts produces the stated result.

Comment: @DanulG: you're welcome.  If the solution is useful to you, please accept it by clicking on the checkmark to the left.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\left.\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin\pars{x^{\alpha}}\dd x
\,\right\vert_{\,\alpha\ >\ 1} =
\sin\pars{\pi \over 2\alpha}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \exp(-x^{\alpha})\,\dd x}:\ {\Large ?}}$.

---

\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\left.\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin\pars{x^{\alpha}}
\dd x\,\right\vert_{\,\alpha\ >\ 1}}
\,\,\,\stackrel{x^{\alpha}\ \mapsto\ x}{=}\,\,\,
{1 \over \alpha}\,\Im\int_{0}^{\infty}
x^{1/\alpha - 1}\,\,\expo{\ic x}\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over \alpha}\,\Im\int_{0}^{\infty}
\ic^{1/\alpha - 1}\,\,\,y^{1/\alpha - 1}\,\,
\expo{-y}\,\ic\,\dd y\quad
\pars{\substack{\mbox{I'll "close" the integral}
\\[0.5mm] \mbox{ along a quarter circle}
\\[0.5mm] \mbox{ in the complex plane}
\\[0,5mm] \mbox{first quadrant.}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over \alpha}\sin\pars{\pi \over 2\alpha}
\int_{0}^{\infty}y^{1/\alpha - 1}\,\,\expo{-y}\,\dd y
\\[5mm] \stackrel{y\ =\ x^{\alpha}}{=}\,\,\,&
{1 \over \alpha}\sin\pars{\pi \over 2\alpha}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\pars{x^{\alpha}}^{1/\alpha - 1}\,\,\expo{-x^{\alpha}}\pars{\alpha x^{\alpha - 1}}\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{\sin\pars{\pi \over 2\alpha}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\expo{-x^{\alpha}}\dd x} \\ &
\end{align}